# Spring Rest Doc (Gradle) Snippets disappear upon build

Tags: spring-restdocs

Recently switch to Gradle from Maven.

Following this tutorial for continuous REST Doc build with Gradle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5ncCJBarRI&t=1490s

Snippets are generating just fine when running test.  Its when I am trying to generate asciidoc where it seems like the /build directory gets recreated without the snippets.  So my generated html always shows

```
Unresolved directive in index.adoc - include::{snippets}/home-json/curl-request.adoc[]
```

I am generating the asciidoc by the following command in the terminal

```
gradle asciidoctor -t

// Continuous build command
// Mentioned around @1:07:40 mark
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5ncCJBarRI&t=1490s
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'lab.restdocs'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}


bootJar {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from ("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/docs'
    }
}
```

**MyTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Rule
    public final JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();


    @InjectMocks
    private HelloController helloController;

    @Mock
    private HelloService helloService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // create a mock environment of helloController
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(helloController)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/hello/string"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("hello there"))
                )
                .andDo(document("home-string"));

    }
```

I also checked my `build.gradle` against https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-restdocs/ and https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html5/#configuration-uris. I don't know what I am missing...

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

Ran command `gradle asciidoctor --console=plain`

If it makes it easier I greated a Git repo
https://github.com/erich5168/edu.rest-doc

```
 erichuang$ gradle asciidoctor --console=plain
> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test

> Task :asciidoctor
asciidoctor: WARNING: api.adoc: line 3: include file not found: /Users/erichuang/Desktop/JE/00-Development/dev/lab/lab-rest-docs/lab.restdocs-gradlebuild/build/generated-snippets/home/curl-request.adoc
asciidoctor: WARNING: api.adoc: line 5: include file not found: /Users/erichuang/Desktop/JE/00-Development/dev/lab/lab-rest-docs/lab.restdocs-gradlebuild/build/generated-snippets/home/http-request.adoc
asciidoctor: WARNING: api.adoc: line 7: include file not found: /Users/erichuang/Desktop/JE/00-Development/dev/lab/lab-rest-docs/lab.restdocs-gradlebuild/build/generated-snippets/home/http-response.adoc
asciidoctor: WARNING: api.adoc: line 20: include file not found: /Users/erichuang/Desktop/JE/00-Development/dev/lab/lab-rest-docs/lab.restdocs-gradlebuild/build/generated-snippets/home-json/http-response.adoc

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Apples-MBP:lab.restdocs-gradlebuild erichuang$
```

Comment: What changes are you making to trigger a build when the snippets disappear and what tasks is Gradle running as a result of those changes? You may want to run Gradle with `--console=plain` to make its behaviour easier to see.

Comment: 1. Run test to generate the snippets.  2. `gradle asciidoctor` or `gradle asciidoctor -t`. 3. Snippets disapears. 4. HTML unresolved directive in.

I have updated my tasks on the post.

Comment: I added git repo... hopefully its eaiser to trouble shoot. Thank you for helping, very grateful!  I just don't understand, I think I have followed the documentation + examples through and through...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When run from the command line, you build isn't running any tests. The tests aren't being run as your tests are using JUnit 4 while the `test` task has been configured to use the JUnit Platform (JUnit 5):

```
test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

You can fix the problem either by updating your tests to use JUnit 5 or by removing `useJUnitPlatform()` from the `test` task's configuration so that it uses JUnit 4. The latter is the smaller change and leaves the `test` task looking like this:

```
test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you... This was particularily hard to catch could you share the steps you took to trouble shoot this?  By the way, anyway we could improve the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration   Because I used Spring initializr to generat my project, and the build.gradle test task already included useJunitPlatform() which is not mentioned anywhere in the doc.

Comment: There weren't that many steps. I ran the build and noticed that no test report was generated (nothing in `build/reports`. I then looked at the `build.gradle` file to see what test framework was being used and the source of the tests. At that point I noticed the mismatch between the code and the build's configuration.

As for the documentation, what sort of improvement would you like to see?  The docs describe the REST Docs specific steps for JUnit 4 and JUnit 5. A general description of how to configure Maven or Gradle to use JUnit 5 is out of scope of the REST Docs reference documentation.

Comment: Perhaps under "Build configuration"-> under foot note 5: To configure `test` tasks to use Junit Platform(JUnit5) add `userJUnitPlateform()`.  And myabe "Generate Document snippets > Setting Up Your JUnit5 Test" you could reference back to "Build configuration"...   Not sure... I think by doing so, makes a clearer distinction JUnit4 / JUnit5 `test` task configuration.